# How does these 2 functions act as getters and setters?

Tags: c++, matrix, getter-setter

I'm studying matrix operations, and out teacher provided us this 3 next functions:

```
//methods used as GETTERS and SETTERS - to access the matrix elements
    float& mat3::at(int i, int j) {
        return matrixData[i + 3 * j];
    }

    const float& mat3::at(int i, int j) const {
        return matrixData[i + 3 * j];
    }

    mat3& mat3::operator =(const mat3& srcMatrix) {
        //usage example for the "at" getter/setter methods
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                //at(i,j) acts as a setter
                //srcMatrix.at(i, j) is used as a getter
                at(i, j) = srcMatrix.at(i, j);
            }   
        }

        return (*this);
    }
```

I get that 'srcMatrix.at(i,j)' acts as a getter, that's pretty obvious, because the fucntions returns the value at that location. But I can't understand why it acts as a setter as well, there is no assignment. And which one of the 'at' functions is a getter and which is a setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first member function `float& mat3::at(int i, int j)` can be used as a setter. Because it returns a non-`const` reference you can assign to it's result to change the matrix's elements.

For example `srcMatrix.at(i,j) = 4.2;` will set the element that position to `4.2`.

The second overload `const float& mat3::at(int i, int j) const` can only act as a getter. The result is a `const` reference so it's not possible to assign to the result. Its  provided so that it's still possible to get the value of an element if you have a `const mat3`.

Comment: Also worth mentioning neither returns a value.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Both of these member functions returns an lvalue reference. Therefore, calling either of these member functions results it an lvalue expression. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "neither returns a value".

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, nothing wrong with your answer. OP mentioned 'returns the value at location`.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Well, since "value" isn't a strictly define term in C++, what that means is up to interpretation. It depends if you consider a `T&` to have the value of the `T` is refers to. In most context it's more useful to consider that it does. I don't think there is any other meaningful value you can attribute to a reference.